# EF Select inside Select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following EF Expression:

```
var complexes = db.ResidentialComplexes.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(rc => rc.MasterEntity == entity)
                .Select(rc => new CustomComplexObj()
                {
                    ComplexId = rc.ComplexId,
                    Name = rc.Name,
                    Region = rc.Region,

                    Properties = rc.CurrentProperties.Select(p=> new CustomPropertyObj(){
                         Name = p.Name,
                         PropertyId = p.PropertyId
                    }).ToList()

                }).ToList();
```

Im getting an error when setting:

```
Properties = rc.CurrentProperties.Select(p=> new CustomPropertyObj(){
                             Name = p.Name,
                             PropertyId = p.PropertyId
                        }).ToList()
```

This is the error:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CondoTrack.Model.Poco.CustomPropertyObj] ToList[CustomPropertyObj](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CondoTrack.Model.Poco.CustomPropertyObj])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Any clue on how to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ToList()` and change the `Properties` type to `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`. As it is stated in the error, `ToList` is not supported by Linq to Entities.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot André! Just waiting to accept the answer.